# Powershell recursively copy and change name of files

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm programming a script to recursively create a copy of many files in Windows Powershell (version: 5.1), with that specifications:

- The file to copy must contain in his name `"*1.dat"` (the asterisk is the rest of the file name)
- The new file must be copied in the same folder of the original file
- The new file Replaces the string `"*1.dat"` with `"*0.dat"` in his file name

I managed to create a `first_script.ps1` with:

```
$directories = dir -Recurse -Directory

$directories | ForEach-Object {
 & ".\second_script.ps1" $_.FullName
}
```

This script passes all directories and subdirectories recursively discovered.

The `second_script.ps1`:

```
$path = $_.FullName  //This assign the value passed to '$path'
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$path\temp"  //Create a new temporary folder
Copy-Item * -Include *1.dat -Destination "$path\temp\"  //Copy all the items filtered in the temp folder
rename-item $path\temp\* -NewName {$_.name -replace "1.dat", "0.dat") //Should replace 1.dat with 0.dat
Copy-Item $path\temp\* -Include *0.dat //Copy renamed items to the primary folder
Remove-Item -Path "$path\temp" -Force -Recurse //Remove temp folder
```

But: the `$_.name` pipeline does not work, probably because I'm already passing the folder path with `$_`.

How to solve? Or, there is a way much easier to do this? I can use windows batch too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever go back to batch!

Preliminary testing shows this should be all you need. You can safely run it as the `-WhatIf` parameter prevents actual execution. Remove the `-WhatIf` if results look good.

```
gci *1.dat -Recurse |
   Copy-Item -Destination { $_.FullName -replace '1\.dat$', '0.dat'  } -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

Observing: ***I can use windows batch too.***

For the record, `bat/cmd` can be done like this:

- In command line, if is the current folder:

```bat
@for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where /r . *1.dat')do @cmd /v/c "set "_name=%~ni" && echo\copy "%~i" "%~dpi!_name:~0,-1!0%~xi""
```

- or, if is not current folder:

```bat
@for /f tokens^=* %i in ('where /r "D:\folder" *1.dat')do @cmd /v/c "set "_name=%~ni" && copy "%~i" "%~dpi!_name:~0,-1!0%~xi""
```

- In bat/cmd file:

```bat
@echo off 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('where /r . *1.dat
')do cmd /v/c "set "_name=%%~ni" && copy "%%~i" "%%~dpi!_name:~0,-1!0%%~xi""
```

---

1. Use `for /f` loop to obtain the output command of the `where /r` command recursively, already selecting only the files ending in `1.dat`
2. Save the `_name` of the current file stored in the loop variable `%%~ni` and use it to remove the last character with substring `!_Name:~0,-1!`
3. Use your `copy` command with this syntax:

```bat
Source: %%~i // where provides the full path to output
Target: %%~dpi!_name:~0,-1!0%%~xi"
```

- Where:

```bat
       %%~dpi == drive: + \all\path\folder
!_name:~0,-1! == name_file_1 = name_file_ // without extension
            0 == add 0 to replace 1 removed by !_name:~0,-1!  
        %%~xi == original extension of your file
```

- For file/path `"D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2\file_1.dat"` your command looks like:

```bat
Source: "D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2\file_1.dat"
Target: "D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2\file_0.dat"
```

- The target will be:

```bat
[D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2] + [file_] + [0] + [.dat]
```

- You command syntax result:

```bat
copy "D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2\file_1.dat" "D:\Q1561229\sub 1\sub 2\file_0.dat"
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Where](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)**

  [√] **[Where sample](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**